# How to see the performance utilization of dataset functions

Tags: c#, performance, dataset

I need help with tools to see performance of the functions in a dataset, a dataset profiler if such thing exists.  Background:

I am giving maintenance to one application previously developed in C# that uses MS-SQL and the access is through datasets.  The previous developer did not consider that the DB will grow this much and since all operations and calculations are done directly against the DB, it's now taking too much time.

I built a memory cache where I load first all elements of the DB and I am planning to do all the calculations against this cache, storing the results in the DB.  Since there are literally hundreds of functions in the dataset, what tool(s) can I use to see what are the functions that consume most of the time, so I can focus in re-programing those to get some quick gains?

Comment: I would recommend using Entity rather than SQLClient class.  The SQLClient class interface to the database is much slow than Entity.  In This case I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel when this question has been asked lots of times before.

Comment: @jdweng Please tell me where has this been asked and answered before (I did search).  I am specifically looking for which functions of the dataset are the ones called the most, spending most of the time in the whole program.  Instead of doing calculations against the DB, doing them in memory sounds by far more efficient, that is all I am trying to achieve.

Any links to Entity?  I am not sure if I have used it before.

Comment: I've worked with a very large database ~10GB using SQL Express,  Using SSMS the queries run in under 30 seconds and returned a lot of data.  The same queries in c# (using same sever) were taking over 30 minutes.  The queries used combination of SELECT and JOIN.  Entity creates classes in c# that map to datatables in a database.  Then in c# reading/writing to classes automatically reads and updates the database.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the link, yes, this seems to be faster ... even though it seems like I will need to rewrite the whole code, I think is still worth.  Regardless, I am still curious, anything out there that can tell me (from a dataset) what functions are the ones used the most, hence consuming time?

Comment: What I did instead of using Entity was to use SQLCMD.EXE (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/overview-sql-tools?view=sql-server-2017).  I then used Process Class to run the Command Line Utilty.  These utilities are designed by MSDN to archive large database and run very fast.  I created CSV files with results and then imported the results into my c# application.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, very helpful information ... back to my original question: do you know of any tool that can profile the funtions of a dataset?  Just to detect the ones that are called more often or the ones that consume most of the time in the program.